# how to generate random num with conditions

Tags: python, algorithm

I want to generate 2n-1 random integers in the range [1,n] with each element appearing twice except for random value, which only appears once.
for example:

```
n = 3  
seq = [1, 2, 3, 1, 3]
```

in this example 2 appears only once.

My algorithm is to use dictionary, like this:

```
-------------
| num |times|
|  1  |  2  |
|  2  |  1  |
|  3  |  2  |
```

where the keys are from 1 to n and the value represents the number of occurrences of the key. I fill the dictionary with values of two and reduce the value to 1 for one random key.

1. Is there any other algorithm?
2. how to do it if n is very large lead to can not be stored in memory?

Comment: If I edited your intention correctly, your method generates the counts needed to create the sequence but doesn't generate a sequence as shown in your example.

Comment: What is this really for?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I am not sure that I am 100 sure what you are after, but here is a try:

```
import random as rn

x = range(3)*2 #generate a list where each number appears twice

rn.shuffle(x) #shuffle it
x.pop()       #remove one number
```

Result:

```
>>> x
[2, 0, 2, 1, 0] #the result is a list where every number appears twice, except for
                #one number which was removed at random, also the numbers are 
                #randomly arranged
```

EDIT:

Here is a try to do this for very large n (an n that a list of that size cannot be stored in your ram). I cannot see how to shuffle the integers. However, I can remove one at random. Let's say you want to write the list to txt file.

```
drop = rn.range(0,n) #choose a random integer to drop

with open('my_file.txt','w') as f:
    for ind,ele in enumerate(xrange(n)):  
        if ind == drop: #do not write the element to txt file
            pass
        else:
            f.write(str(ele) + '\n') #write every except for one element to txt file

with open('my_file.txt','a') as f:
    for ele in xrange(n):
        f.write(str(ele) + '\n') # write every element to txt file
```

In the end we were wrote n-1 element to txt file two times, and 1 element once, that element was chosen at random.

For n = 5 the txt file looks like this:

```
0
2
3
4
0
1
2
3
4
```

In the above case 1 is only showing up once, every other number is showing up twice.

Comment: This would have the undesirable property that the rightmost item only would be popped, which is rather non-random. `del x[random.range(0, len(x)-1]` would be better than pop.

Comment: @msw The rightmost item is entirely random since the pop occurs after the shuffle.

Comment: this is really feasible. and I want to know how I can do it if n is very large?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel: agreed, the question is open to multiple interpretations.

Comment: This is really helpful to me.

Comment: @msw Removing a random item is no better than popping the last one, given the elements are fairly shuffled.

Answer (score 0):

As with @Akavall, not sure if I understand you correctly. You want to generate 2n-1 numbers in range of 1 to n (including n I assume). The numbers are not really random then, only the one which has 1 occurence.

```
import random

n=3

# Generate n numbers
numbers = [i for i in range(1,n+1)]
# Concatenate list to itself (now have 2n numbers)
numbers *= 2
# Remove a random element in the list (now have 2n-1 numbers)
numbers.pop( random.randint(0, len(numbers)-1) )

# Print results
from collections import Counter
print( Counter(numbers) )
```

Output

```
Counter({1: 2, 3: 2, 2: 1})
```

Answer (score 0):

> 2․ how to do it if n is very large lead to can not be stored in memory?

Depends on what you want to do with these numbers and on whether or not the order is important. Judging from the way you present the table I'd say you don't care about order, so even with large `n`, the actual amount of information required to encode the entire table is very small: `n` itself and the index for which there is only one entry.

It might be better to change your approach completely if you think memory is going to be an issue, but without more information it's hard to say.

Answer (score 0):

1) I would recommend using a random number generator to select your "single" number, then I would use build a collection of all of your numbers then use the built in shuffle method. I recommend using the build in shuffle method, because the built in methods tend to be highly optimized.

- Java Collection Reference:
  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html
- Java shuffle Reference:
  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle(java.util.List)

2) If n is very large, then you might want to write chunks of the numbers to files and do shuffling on only portions at any given time. An analogy of this is trying to shuffle 5 decks of cards at the same time. It would be very difficult at best, however you can take portions of the large collection and shuffle those portions together, return the portions to the large collection and select two more portions to shuffle, repeat until you meet your desired shuffling requirements.

Comment: This is a Python question, not Java.

Answer (score 0):

Generator for the resulting frequency table, this should help with memory issues

```
from random import randint

def generate_counts(n):
    remove_index = randint(1,n+1)
    return ((i+1,2-(remove_index==i)) for i in range(n))
```

Output

```
for number, frequency in generate_counts(10):
    print "%i: %i"%(number,frequency)

1: 2
2: 2
3: 2
4: 1
5: 2
6: 2
7: 2
8: 2
9: 2
10: 2
```